# Why do I suddenly start losing money?

Tags: cities-skylines

Whenever I have been playing in my city for around 5-6 hours, I start suddenly losing money. This has happened to me twice. Why does this happen to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a variety of reasons your city could be losing money. Without more detail it’s hard to determine the exact cause.

Some of the more likely causes is you’re over-building your city. Throughout the game you want to keep your city services roughly in parity with the needs of your citizens. As an example, buying dozens of parks to prove your land value might be worth it late in your city’s lifespan but doing it too early will create upkeep expenses that are hard to surmount.

Another common expense is zoning a district and district policies to it. Many district policies charge a fixed rate for each building they affect. If you zone a whole region and apply a district policy to it, if the district grows fast enough it can surprise you by how expensive the policies can become.

Lastly, and I’m not completely certain of this, citizens affected by conditions don’t seem to pay taxes. If you have a large segment of citizens all getting sick at once your income tanks. If all commercial buildings are unable to find enough workers because you destroyed a road to your commercial district, your income will tank even if the buildings themselves are still standing.

Answer (score 1):

According to Reddit, the main suggestion is to turn off electric and water policies.
They cost a fortune and for most buildings it's more than it costs to just generate additional water and electric. Water and energy conservation policies are not to save money but water/energy resources.